# How do I use reduce to calculate the total of a value in an object

Tags: javascript

```js
const people = [
    { name: 'Matt', friend: true, awesomeLevel: 10 },
    { name: 'Matias', friend: true, awesomeLevel: 10 },
    { name: 'Catie', friend: false, awesomeLevel: 3 },
    { name: 'Samantha', friend: false, awesomeLevel: 4 },
    { name: 'Jonathan', friend: true, awesomeLevel: 8 },
    { name: 'Josh', friend: true, awesomeLevel: 7 }
]


let totallyAwesome = people.reduce((acc, ele) => acc + ele.awesomeLevel)
console.log(totallyAwesome)
```

So I'm trying to use reduce to get the whole total added up of awesomeLevel

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a *initialValue* for the accumulator. Otherwise the first element is taken as start value for [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const people = [
    { name: 'Matt', friend: true, awesomeLevel: 10 },
    { name: 'Matias', friend: true, awesomeLevel: 10 },
    { name: 'Catie', friend: false, awesomeLevel: 3 },
    { name: 'Samantha', friend: false, awesomeLevel: 4 },
    { name: 'Jonathan', friend: true, awesomeLevel: 8 },
    { name: 'Josh', friend: true, awesomeLevel: 7 }
];


let totallyAwesome = people.reduce((acc, ele) => acc + ele.awesomeLevel, 0);
//                                                                       ^

console.log(totallyAwesome);
```

Answer (score 0):

You only forget the starting-value `0` in your reduce at the end as second parameter (just after the callback).

```js
const people = [
    { name: 'Matt', friend: true, awesomeLevel: 10 },
    { name: 'Matias', friend: true, awesomeLevel: 10 },
    { name: 'Catie', friend: false, awesomeLevel: 3 },
    { name: 'Samantha', friend: false, awesomeLevel: 4 },
    { name: 'Jonathan', friend: true, awesomeLevel: 8 },
    { name: 'Josh', friend: true, awesomeLevel: 7 }
]


let totallyAwesome = people.reduce((acc, {awesomeLevel}) => acc + awesomeLevel, 0);
console.log(totallyAwesome)
```

Comment: Destructuring in this case is quite inefficient - it's less readable and requires more typing and is likely slightly slower.

Comment: @ Klaycon - More typing ok (I use copying), readability it's opinionbased and I would assume that destructing is faster but I don't know much enough for the intern processes besides this.